# React - api call returns undefineds

Tags: axios, react-hooks, use-effect

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [meal, setMeal] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get('/random.php');
      setMeal(response.data.meals);
      setLoading(false);
      return response;
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card className={classes.Root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia className={classes.Media} title="food">
          <img src={meal[0].strMealThumb} alt="cat" />
        </CardMedia>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {meal[0].strMeal}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {meal[0].strInstructions}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
```

I'm using the coed above but I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'strMealThumb' of undefined. I tried multiple ways with useEffect and still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your component renders for the first time, the network request to `/random.php` hasn't happened yet, so `meal` is set to its default value (`[]`). You're attempting to set the image source to `meal[0].strMealThumb`, but `meal` is an empty array, so `meal[0]` returns `undefined`, and you see the error you posted.

The solution is to prevent the component body from rendering while `meal` is loading, and when `meal` is an empty array (in case `/random.php` returns an empty array).

`meal` is an array, so you should name it `meals` instead.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  if (meals.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>No meals found!</div>
    );
  }

  return ( /* ... */ );
};
```

Comment: it worked and I renamed to meals as suggested. Thank you :D